# How to ensure a webapp is compatible with any context path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, contextpath

I'm working on an existing webapp that has always been deployed to root (i.e. `http://localhost/`); now I need it to be accessible through an explicit context path (i.e. `http://localhost/sub`).

I'm hitting several road blocks, though, from servlets code breaking due to the `/context-path` in the request uri, to URL's in HTML pages that send the browser to unavailable paths (i.e. `src="/include/scripts/main.js"`).

Although I almost managed all the cases where pure logic is involved (servlets can be made so that reading `request.getRequestUri()` gives a uri free of the context path), the biggest trouble is URL's in JSP pages, which are usually expressed starting from `/` (this is a requirement, because some paths need to be *global*, i.e. not bound to the current page).

So, my question is: if I were to start a whole new webapp, what steps should I take to be sure that it will be deployable under any context?

Would prepending:

```
<%= request.getContextPath() %>
```

to any URL, e.g. `<img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/bluedot.png"/>` be enough?

What about paths in static resources such as CSS files?

Comment: What about still putting all files in project root, despite working on some other context path? For example okay, your servlets respond to http://localhost/sub, but your jsps are in /jsp/* so call to /jsp/someJsp.jsp will be ok

Comment: request.getContextPath() should be fine all all sort of resources,static or otherwise!